# How to simplify algebra equations represented as list of list

Tags: list, prolog, algebra

With Prolog I want to simplify [algebra expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_expression) represented as as list of list:

algebra equation

```
f = 3x+2
```

list of list

```
[[3,1],[2,0]]
```

`3` and `2` are coefficients
`1` and `0` are exponents

That should be obvious.

I am looking for some tips or suggestions on how to code the simplifications for this example:

```
f = 3x+2x+1+2
[[3,1],[2,1],[1,0],[2,0]]
```

simplified:

```
f = 5x+3
[[5,1],[3,0]]
```

I have tried some built in functions but did not get the proper idea about how to use them.

Comment: Is there an error in your example? `f=3x+2x+1+2` should be `[[3,1],[2,1],[1,0],[2,0]]` instead of `[[1,3],[2,1],[1,0],[2,0]]`?

Comment: yes thank you, corrected

Comment: Do you also want to solve systems of equations?

Comment: Is this all about polynomial expressions of one variable?

Comment: yes it is all about one variable only , solving systéme i did it , but can oyu a afoard with a solution manipulating only lists ?

Answer (score 3):

One liner, similar to what's proposed by joel76:

```
simplify(I,O) :-
    bagof([S,E],L^(bagof(C,member([C,E],I),L),sum_list(L,S)),O).
```

The inner bagof collects `C` (coefficients) given `E` (exponents), the resulting list `L` is summed into `S`, and paired with `E` becomes `[S,E]`, an element (monomial) of O.
If you omit the universal quantification specifier (that is `L^`) you get single monomials on backtracking.

Comment: I used a predsort to get **Out = [[5, 1], [3, 0]] ;**, you get **Out = [[3, 0], [5, 1]].** I don't know if this is important !

Comment: monomials order should be unimportant, i think. BTW aggregate is based on setof etc, so ordering is already implied

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem in this way:

```
simplify(_,_,S,S,[]):- !.
simplify(L,I,Sum,NTot,[[I,S]|T]):-
    Sum =< NTot,
    findall(X,member([X,I],L),LO),
    length(LO,N),
    S1 is Sum + N,
    sum_list(LO,S),
    I1 is I+1,
    simplify(L,I1,S1,NTot,T).           

write_function([]).
write_function([[D,V]|T]):-
    write(' + '),write(V),write('x^'),write(D),
    write_function(T).

test:-
    L = [[3,1],[2,1],[1,0],[2,0]],
    length(L,N),
    simplify(L,0,0,N,LO), 
    LO = [[D,V]|T],
    write('f='),write(V),write('x^'),write(D),
    write_function(T).
```

The main predicate is `simplify/5` which uses `findall/3` to find all the coefficients with the same degree and then sums them using `sum_list/2`. Then you can write the result in a fancy way using `write_function/1`.

Comment: thank you so much , but can you afoard me a solution using only list manupilation?

Answer (score 2):

In SWI-Prolog You can use aggregate :

```
pred(>, [_,X], [_,Y]) :- X > Y.
pred(<, [_,X], [_,Y]) :- X < Y.
pred(=, [_,X], [_,X]).

simplify(In, Out) :-
    aggregate(set([S,X]), aggregate(sum(P), member([P,X], In), S), Temp),
    predsort(pred, Temp, Out).
```

For example :

```
?- simplify([[3,1],[2,1],[1,0],[2,0]], Out).
Out = [[5, 1], [3, 0]] ;
false.
```

Comment: thank you so much , but can you afoard me a solution using only list manupilation?